# Set Credentials to Content Deployment Job

Tags: 2013, powershell, content-deployment

We are using Sharepoint 2013 but is there any programmatic way to set the Credentials for a Content Deployment job? Set-SPContentDeploymentPath seems to be close but the documentation doesn't actually list any parameters as taking an identity (username and password):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608100.aspx

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Ugh ... i was looking right past it ... there is the PathAccount parameter that takes a System.Management.Automation.PSCredential. Sorry for the question!